# Adding vertical divider in <li> to create 'section' with separate active and hover states

Tags: html, css

My website navigation [looks something like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oKpLY.png) in the mobile view. I'm struggling to achieve the vertical line/divider between the '*menu item text*' and the '*+ or -*' icon.

I'm looking for this section to be clickable and have a separate hover and active state to the rest of the `<li>`.

What is the best method to achieve this using the markup and CSS I have?

Thanks :)

**HTML**

```
<ul>
<li class="submenu">
    <a href="#"><span class="btn-text">Menu item 1</span></a>
    <div class="nav-2">
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="#"><span class="btn-text">Child 1</span></a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#"><span class="btn-text">Child 2</span></a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#"><span class="btn-text">Child 3</span></a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</li> </ul>
```

The + and - icon are a CSS background on the 'submenu' class.

```
    background: url(plus.svg) no-repeat 95% center;
    background-color: #383738;
    background-size: 20px;
```

Comment: Hi and welcome. You would have to give your full related css for this as well. We don't know how any of it looks. One thing I could spot and give a recommendation on is don't use an `<a href="#">` if it's not a link, use a `<button>text</button>` for that purpose.

Comment: you have given very limited code. but try putting border to the + icon and put margin on it. it will create same effect.